# Change Catalina login screen password prompt retries

Tags: keyboard, catalina, password, login

When I login to Catalina, having fat fingers, I quite often mistype my password. Then up pops an unhelpful box saying "If you forgot your password, you can ...".

I haven't forgotten my password, I have just mistyped it, you stupid machine!

I haven't found a way of dismissing that box without resorting to a mouse click (I'd prefer not to take my finger from the keyboard.) Is there a way of setting say a number of password retries allowed before the "helpful" box pops up?

Comment: what if you hit `Tab` to move to the next button/field then press `Enter`?

Comment: @Allan I have the login window set to "Name and Password". The `Tab` key does nothing.